# Checkout conflict with files git pull

Tags: eclipse, git, git-pull, git-checkout

Yesterday I made a pull in Eclipse from my team repository and it worked perfectly. But today I have tried to pull and the following message appears:

```
Checkout conflict with files: 

.....(Here is my project and the window that is affected)

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.ChechoutConflictException
```

One of my partners has made changes but not at the same time that me. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflict in some file. Usually you can solve it using some kind of merging tool. [Check this tutorial.](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)

If you do a "git status" from the command line you will get the conflicting files, update your question with the output to get better answers.